# Can't set 1920x1080 as custom resolution with xrandr

Tags: virtualbox, display-resolution, xrandr

I got a problem with Ubuntu on my Virtual machine (Virtual Box), what happens is that I can't find 1920x1080 resolution which is my screen's native resolution even though I can find higher ones like 1920x1200,
I tried using xrandr to create this custom resolution:
`xrandr --newmode "1920x1080"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync`
`xrandr --addmode Virtual1 1920x1080`

When I try to use it with `xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60`
it gives me crtc0 failed error

I tried enabling 3D acceleration, I installed the extension pack, I tried setting allocated VRAM higher, I set allocated RAM to 2048 MB and CPU cores to 2, I don't exactly know what's happening as this is my first time ever with Linux, My Ubuntu release is 20.04.2.0

Comment: You likely do not need the `--rate 60` at the end of the final step: `xrandr --output Virtual1 --mode "1920x1080"`